# How to just get text BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, output, output-formatting

I am a first time poster. I'm making a program to tell the weather with requests and BeautifulSoup that is formatting the proper information wrong. I have

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/91ae3bca47e7dbeb23a6f4b10cb656d234e65f12a1e9b4dc80a0e02e5baa838c'


def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


htmldata = getdata(
    "https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/91ae3bca47e7dbeb23a6f4b10cb656d234e65f12a1e9b4dc80a0e02e5baa838c")

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')

precip = soup.find('div', id='WxuTodayWeatherCard-main-486ce56c-74e0-4152-bd76-7aea8e98520a')

currentPrecip = precip.find('li')

for j in currentPrecip:
    showPrecip = currentPrecip.get_text()

result = f"Current Temp: {showPrecip}"

print(result)
```

The program is outputting `Current Temp: Morning-5°Snow--` and I want it to output `Current Temp: -5°C, Sky Snow`

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Whats the website url?

Comment: The website url is https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/91ae3bca47e7dbeb23a6f4b10cb656d234e65f12a1e9b4dc80a0e02e5baa838c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not that clear, your taking the forecast and expect the current data. This may should be improved.

Current:

```
live = soup.select_one('div.styles--card--3aeCQ a')
print(f"Current Temp: {live.find('span').get_text()}, Sky: {live.find('svg').get_text()}")
```

Forecast (Morning):

```
morning = soup.select_one('section[data-testid="TodayWeatherModule"] ul>li')
print(f"Current Temp: {morning.div.span.get_text()}, Sky: {morning.find('title').get_text()}")
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/91ae3bca47e7dbeb23a6f4b10cb656d234e65f12a1e9b4dc80a0e02e5baa838c'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

live = soup.select_one('div.styles--card--3aeCQ a')
print(f"Current Temp: {live.find('span').get_text()}, Sky: {live.find('svg').get_text()}")

morning = soup.select_one('section[data-testid="TodayWeatherModule"] ul>li')
print(f"Current Temp: {morning.div.span.get_text()}, Sky: {morning.find('title').get_text()}")
```

**Output**

```
Current Temp: -2°, Sky: Snow
Current Temp: -5°, Sky: Snow
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. How did you find the lines in the html with the temperature and precipitation values? I'm trying to learn bs4 and how to find useful values from websites, but I am having issues finding anything that makes sense to me.

Comment: Happy to help - Find the lines by inspecting the source code with the chrome developer tools https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html